Dropdown does not work only in Laravel Blade, but on any editor it works great
As already described in the header I'm having a problem.
The dropdown doesn't work in Laravel Blade, but it works on any editor (as you can very well verify below with the code).
I am using Bootstrap 5.0.2


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.7.0/dt-2.1.8/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.7.0/dt-2.1.8/datatables.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js/src/toastify.min.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Kc323vGBEqzTmouAECnVceyQqyqdsSiqLQISBL29aUW4U/M7pSPA/gEUZQqv1cwx4OnYxTxve5UMg5GT6L4JJg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lipis/flag-icons@7.2.3/css/flag-icons.min.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

    <title>Project Laravel</title>
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown link
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/micromodal/dist/micromodal.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js"></script>
</body>

</html>



After many attempts I saw that to make it work I have to add both the cdn of 'Bootstrap Bundle with Popper', that is
<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

and the cdn of 'Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS', that is
    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

(all 3 together, which is not good). (SEE CODE BELOW)


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.7.0/dt-2.1.8/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.7.0/dt-2.1.8/datatables.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js/src/toastify.min.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.6.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Kc323vGBEqzTmouAECnVceyQqyqdsSiqLQISBL29aUW4U/M7pSPA/gEUZQqv1cwx4OnYxTxve5UMg5GT6L4JJg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lipis/flag-icons@7.2.3/css/flag-icons.min.css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

    <title>Project Laravel</title>

    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown link
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/micromodal/dist/micromodal.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js"></script>
</body>

</html>



Now it doesn't work here anymore, while on my Laravel project it works fine.
I know that you don't have to put both options regarding cdn, but I don't know what to do anymore.
Can someone please help me?

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out what went wrong.I finally fixed this.
Make sure that bootstrap is only imported once. It was imported into app.js and my layout.

It looks like the issue is that you're including both the Bootstrap Bundle (with Popper) and the separate Popper and Bootstrap JS scripts, which can cause conflicts. You only need one of them.
Try removing the second set of scripts (Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS) and keep just the Bootstrap Bundle:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

This should resolve the dropdown issue

It doesn't work if you keep only ONE. I have to put all 3, which is a bit absurd.
I also tried only option 2 but it still doesn't work

This only works by putting both the Bootstrap Bundle (with Popper) and the separate Popper and Bootstrap JS scripts

If it only works with all 3 scripts, there might be a conflict elsewhere. Try these steps:


Remove all Bootstrap JS scripts and keep only the Bootstrap Bundle with Popper:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>



Check for conflicts: Ensure there are no other versions of Bootstrap or Popper loaded (through vite, CDN, or app.js).


Check for JavaScript errors in the console that might be causing the dropdown issue.



checked all 3 again, even though I had done it before. Still not working

I don't know what could have happened :(

This answer is generated by AI

@KevinShugul yes you are correct, my english is not so perfect i have used to correct the grammar and words but you are not completely correct

@maurice we can connect over teams or meet.
